import from Excel to MSProject VBA
I created a file in Excel that puts down the fact of the completed work from Excel to MS Project. But I ran into two problems.

How to clear the work assignments completely before uploading by referring to the job ID.
can it be easier to upload data to MS Project?

Example working file
I tried Macrorecorder, but it turns out that the code is linked to strings and only works in this file.
'It's work
Sub SetActualHours()
Dim tsk As Task
Dim names As String
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Dim asn As Assignment
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            If asn.UniqueID = 2097153 Then  '  ID Resource (UID =1048577, [1048577+1048576=2097153] uniqueID + 1048576
                Dim tsv As TimeScaleValues
                Set tsv = asn.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=#6/26/2024#, EndDate:=#6/28/2024# _
                    , Type:=pjAssignmentTimescaledActualWork, TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleDays)
                ' tsv(1).Clear for clear value
                 tsv(1).Value = 60
                 tsv(2).Value = 60
                 
            End If
        Next asn
Next tsk
End Sub

next question, i want clear only work UniqueID = 2097153, but this macro clear all project data, what need fix it in it?
Sub ClearActualHours()
Dim tsk As Task
Dim names As String
projStart = ActiveProject.ProjectStart
projEnd = ActiveProject.ProjectFinish
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Dim asn As Assignment
        For Each asn In tsk.Assignments
            If asn.UniqueID = 2097153 Then
            Dim TSValues As TimeScaleValues
            Set TSValues = asn.TimeScaleData(projStart, projEnd, pjAssignmentTimescaledActualWork, pjTimescaleYears)
                Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
            For Each tsv In TSValues
          tsv.Clear
         Next tsv
        asn.Work = 0
       End If
Next asn
  tsk.Work = 0
     Next tsk
End Sub


Sorry but you can't get there from here with a recorded macro. A recorded macro operates on the active view by selecting rows/fields. What you want/need is a macro that operates directly on Excel and Project objects (i.e. independent of the view). If you only need to transfer static assignment data (not-timescaled) then you might try an import map with a merge key.

hi, if you can tell me how to change this [SelectTimescaleRange Row:=12, StartTime:="22.02.2021", Width:=17, Height:=1 EditDelete] with the addition of a binding to the job ID [SelectTimescaleRange .Tasks.UniqueID(11658), StartTime:="22.02.2021", Width:=17, Height:=1 EditDelete] this not work, i know)

First of all, what is "job ID". There is no such field in Project. Second, screen shots of your Project file and your macro code would be helpful.

this  [Tasks.UniqueID(11658)] TaskID or TASK UID

Okay, so where is the screen shot and your macro code I asked for?

Look at the TimeScaleData method, TimeScaleValues collection and the TimeScaleValue object. Also, search SO for related questions/answers.

SelectTimescaleRange Row:=12, StartTime:="22.02.2021", Width:=17, Height:=1  EditDelete >-This macrorecorder  (for cleadr record UID 11658 ). screen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zMSkLcMS0DCaztQsdNTpA7uVfu7yyzPi/view?usp=sharing .  please I can't make it so that the binding is not to ROW (row 12), but to the job ID (11658)

@РоманИМарина You don't want to use SelectTimescaleRange, use theTimeScaleData method and related objects (see comment above for links to the documentation). Here is a simple example: stackoverflow.com/.../how-do-i-write-actual-hours-with-specific-data/

@RachelHettinger
it doesn't work or I don't understand what needs to be changed in order to make both the fact and clear the value daily, i.e. not put 0 but empty  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVU9x0b8EvBl5EvLKIvT7eL_YQRCYSZo/view?usp=sharing or https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MNV96eH8rchvNnj10cj4KQU2uwHtW1p-/view?usp=sharing

You need to edit your question and post your code and explain which part is not working.

Please help me change find from NAME "TRZ" to ID Resource (example ID , UID = 1048579)

It should be a simple matter of using "If asn.UniqueID = 1048579 Then" but Project throws a curve on assignment uniqueIDs. Namely, what you see in the view and what you see as an object parameter is different by 2^20 (1048576), so what you need to look for in your code is the assignment uniqueID + 1048576

thanks,  its work))) [1048577+1048576=2097153] thank you very much

You're welcome and thanks for the feedback.
